# Laravel validation unique

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a table with a unique column. 
My form validation rules look like this:

```
    return Validator::make($data, [
      'nameEN'   => 'required|string',
      'nameHE'   => 'required|string',
      'address'  => 'required|string|min:10|unique:clients'
    ]);
```

My issue is that when I edit a row, I get a validation error if I haven't changed the address column.

My edit function looks like so:

```
public function editPost(Request $request,$id){
    $client = new Client();
    $client->editValidation($request->all())->validate();
    $row = $client->where('id',$id)->get()->first();
    $update = array();
    if(!empty($request->input("nameEN"))    && $request->input("nameEN")    != $row->nameEN) $update["nameEN"] = $request->input("nameEN");
    if(!empty($request->input("nameHE"))    && $request->input("nameHE")    != $row->nameHE) $update["nameHE"] = $request->input("nameHE");
    if(!empty($request->input("address"))   && $request->input("address")   != $row->address) $update["address"] = $request->input("address");

    if(empty($update)) $message = $this->message("info", "Notic: Client {$row->nameEN} was not updated because nothing was changed.");
    else if($client->where("id",$row->id)->update($update)){
        $message = $this->message("success", "Client {$row->nameEN} was updated.");
    } else {
        $message = $this->message("danger", "Error: Client {$row->nameEN} was not updated.");
    }
    $redirect = redirect("clients");
    if(isset($message)) $redirect->with("message",$message);
    return $redirect;
}
```

If I remove the `unique` from my validation rules I risk the chance of getting a mysql error.

How can this be sorted out?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique):

Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check,
To instruct the validator to ignore the object's ID

```
'address'  => 'required|string|min:10|unique:clients,address,'.$id
```

Or you could do that using `Rule` class

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
   'address' => [
        Rule::unique('clients')->ignore($id),
  ]
]);
```

> If your table uses a primary key column name other than id, you may specify the name of the column when calling the ignore method:

```
'address' => Rule::unique('clients')->ignore($id, 'primary_key')
```

Comment: Thanks man! Second parameter for this ignore method saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

For validating unique column on laravel 5.6:

just for a field on demand use as:

unique:table,column,except,idColumn

```
'address'  => 'required|string|min:10|unique:clients,address,'.$id
```

When you want to use a separate class for validation. I use a common class both for add and update as:

```
public function rules()
{
  if($this->method() == 'POST')
      $address = 'required|string|min:10|unique:clients,address';
  else
     $address  = 'required|string|min:10|unique:clients,address,'.$this->id;
   //put a hidden input field named id with value on your edit view and catch it here; 
    return [
       'nameEN'   => 'required|string',
       'nameHE'   => 'required|string',
       'address'  => $address
    ];
}
```